# Shimmer effect with DYNAMIC background position?

Tags: html, css

I have found that solution on this page. However, the `background-position` prop is... hardcoded (static). It will fail on different screen sizes (its too narrow for 4K screens - will start over in a half, and it's too wide for small screens - it will animate too quickly).

Is there a way to somehow make it dynamic, so it will work properly for every screen size? And if you ask, 100% do not work unfortunately.

```css
@keyframes shimmerBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: -1000px 0
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 1000px 0
  }
}

.shimmer {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  animation: shimmerBackground 1s linear infinite;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='shimmer' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [`vw` (viewport width) / `vh` (viewport height) / `vmin` (viewport shorter edge) / `vmax` (viewport longer edge)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) units.

```
@keyframes shimmerBackground {
  0% {
    background-position: -100vw 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100vw 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand

when changing screen size shimer div height is not changing according

here height is fixed height: 100px;

It can be dynamic like  `height:20%`  or something you like 
If you want to change animation speed

```
animation: shimmerBackground 1s linear infinite;
```

You can change 1s to 3s or something you like

Comment: I dont want to hardcode `background-position` property